# How do I add certificate revocation lists to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, ubuntu-16.04

I try to run a asp.net core server on Ubuntu which sends files on request to an extern client. My task is to secure the connection between server and client via Https. My server uses the local keystore (Crl + RootCertificates) for client authentication. I tested it before on Windows. I added certificates(certs) and certificate revocation lists(crls) to keystore manually and actually all worked fine. 
But onto Ubuntu I got no clue how to add crls  to local keystore. I'm not quite sure whether there is any 'keystore' onto Ubuntu, but I found solutions for adding certs to it. (add certificates to '/etc/ca-certificates' and run command 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates')
So my question is: How do I add certificate revocation lists to Ubuntu?
And maybe there is a similar way to add clrs easily like certs?

I hope there is somebody who knows a bunch more about this and can give me an advice.

Thanks for your help.
H.Tanke